# Cannot POST /users/create error while creating form using nodejs express and mysql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I was creating a form and taking user data, but after filling the details and submitting the form it shows **Cannot POST /users/create**
. Tried but didnt find anything.

**app.js file-**

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require("./database");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/",(req, res) => {
    res.render("users");
})
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const userDetails = req.body;

    const sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
    db.query(sql, userDetails,(err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("user data inserted sucessfully");
    });
    res.redirect('users')
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server created successfully ${port}`);
})
```

**users.ejs file-**

```
<div class="user-detail">
    <h2>Create user data</h2>
    <form action="/users/create" method="POST">
        <label>Full name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name" name="fullName" required>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="emailAddress" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter city name" name="city" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter country name" name="country" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Output-
database created successfully
server started successfully

Comment: In your backend you defined your route as `/create`, not `/users/create`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but your routes doesn't match.
In your ejs file you wrote: `<form action='users/create'....>`
In your app.js file the route in your post request is:

```
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {...}
```

You have to call the same endpoint in your frontend as defined in your backend.

Comment: I have tried doing that, but it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you [mount](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) your `app` on the `/users` path:

```js
express().use("/users", require("./app.js")).listen(80);
```

but not if you run it "standalone":

```js
require("./app.js").listen(80);
```